# Change the label of choices in ModelchoiceField

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have a group model with 2 instances: groupA and GroupB. I am retrieving those values into my SignupForm with the ModelChoiceField. I need to give those 2 Groups other labels, lets say LabelA and LabelB due to UX design. I made a workaround by adding a new field (Slug) to the Group model that stores that Label value for each of the Group instances. I changed the Query set to make it retrieve the values of the Slug field. As expected I cant Signup like this because the two fields have different values.

Is there a way to, or label the choices of the first queryset i made, or is there some kind of workaround to associate?

forms.py

```
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    user_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CustomGroup.objects.values_list('slug', flat=True),
                                        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'placeholder': 'Soort klant:'}),
                                        initial='Voor jezelf',
                                        help_text=''
                                        )
    # first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Voornaam',
    #                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Voornaam'}),)
    # last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Achternaam',
    #                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Achternaam'}),)

    field_order = ('user_group', 'email') #, 'first_name', 'last_name',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.fields['user_group'].label = ""
        self.helper.error_text_inline = False
```

custom_adapter.py

```
class UserAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):

        user = super(UserAccountAdapter, self).save_user(request, user, form, commit=False)
        user.user_group = form.cleaned_data.get('user_group')
        user.save()
        user.groups.add(user.user_group)
        if user.groups.filter(name='zakelijk').exists():
            user.is_active = False
        else:
            user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, What do you mean by *displayed value*? Can you add a screenshot  or something?

Comment: The Group model of my django authentication back-end has two main values groupA and groupB. I just need to alter these in the front-end so that the user sees labelA for the value of groupA and labelB for the value of groupB.